# Asynchronous DLL access in LabVIEW?

Tags: dll, labview

I have a LabVIEW application that current sends data to a C++ application via a DLL.  I now need to send data back to the LabVIEW app from the C++ one.  Can I trigger code in LabVIEW from a DLL call or will I need to poll the DLL periodically to see if new data is waiting?

Or am I going about this in completely the wrong way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible to generate an event from C++ to trigger a normal LabVIEW event.
[Here](http://forums.ni.com/ni/board/message?board.id=170&thread.id=332674) is a NI forums post discussing this structure.
And a code excerpt from that thread:

```
#include <utility.h>
#include <extcode.h>
#include "EventDLL.h"
//Generate a LabVIEW event
int GenerateLVEvent(LVUserEventRef *msg, int param)
{
PostLVUserEvent( *msg, (void *)&param);
return 0;
}
```

And here's the original sourcecode as a PNG:
[image]
<sub>(source: [vi-lib.com](http://vi-lib.com/forForum/eventDLL.PNG))</sub>  
And here is the accompanying LabVIEW code:
[image]
The lower loop is LabVIEW code that sends a DLL event to the LabVIEW event handler.
This should be placed inside your DLL.
One of the input parameters should be the event pointer as a U32.

Good luck,

Ton

PS if you are going do dive into DLLs and LabVIEW interoperability, pay attention to everything RolfK says, he is a guru in that field.

Comment: Between this and the occurrence examples in the linked thread I should be good to go.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, an occurence is a simple version of events.